# Executing command inside pod from outside

Tags: kubernetes

I have a deployment that creates pods on demand with an image and a volume mounted to it.

I have to exec a command in the pod to start up the service, but only once the node is running (hence why I am not doing it in the docker image).

How can I run a command inside the pod from outside (ie like a .sh file I can run from outside the cluster that will exec into the pods and run the command?)

**Update:** I found that using the `command:` header in the yaml will allow you to overwrite the `ENTRYPOINT` in the Dockerfile. 
See [here](http://blog.phymata.com/2017/07/29/inject-an-executable-script-into-a-container-in-kubernetes/)

My new issue is that i don't know which is first; the volume being mounted or the command being run (I assume the latter). I need to have some contents from the volume before i can run the command. Any advice will be appreciated.

Comment: Hi, As I understand, firstly volumes are mounted then the container will be started. init-container create a network and filesystem namespace for main application container

Answer (score 4):

```
$ kubectl exec --help
Execute a command in a container.

Options:
  -c, --container='': Container name. If omitted, the first container in the pod will be chosen
  -p, --pod='': Pod name
  -i, --stdin=false: Pass stdin to the container
  -t, --tty=false: Stdin is a TTY

Usage:
  kubectl exec POD [-c CONTAINER] -- COMMAND [args...] [options]
```

Addition to [Alex's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48765537/executing-command-inside-pod-from-outside/48766200#48766200)

If you have multiple Containers in your Pod, you need to specify Container name, otherwise, you will exec into first Container.

```
kubectl exec -it -n <namespace-name> <pod-name> -c <container-name> -- COMMAND [args...]
```

Read details about [kubectl exec](https://kubernetes-v1-4.github.io/docs/user-guide/kubectl/kubectl_exec/)

Answer (score 3):

For the initial question, something like the following would work:

```
kubectl exec -it pod --namespace=namespace cat /etc/hosts
```

Obviously change the pod name, namespace and command.

With regards to your update, the volume is created first, I know from mounting persistent storage for mongo containers then on startup the mongo entrypoint writes data to this location.